# Setting text to a custom dialog class

Tags: android, dialog

I am setting text to a custom dialog box. I am getting a `NullPointerException`. The dialog is called when a `listItem` is clicked. **EDIT, Scroll to the bottom to see updated code.** Or See here:

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            HomeItem homeItem = (HomeItem) adapter.getItem(position);
            DialogClass dialogClass = new DialogClass(databaseFightCard.this);
            dialogClass.setDialog(homeItem.getHomeItemRedName(), homeItem.getHomeItemRedAge(), homeItem.getHomeItemRedRecord(),
                    homeItem.getHomeItemRedHeight(), homeItem.getHomeItemRedWeight(), homeItem.getHomeItemRedCity(), homeItem.getHomeItemRedExp(),
                    homeItem.getHomeItemBlueName(), homeItem.getHomeItemBlueAge(), homeItem.getHomeItemBlueRecord(), homeItem.getHomeItemBlueHeight(),
                    homeItem.getHomeItemBlueWeight(), homeItem.getHomeItemBlueCity(), homeItem.getHomeItemBlueExp());

            dialogClass.show();

        }
    });
```

**DialogClass**

```
 public class DialogClass extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

public Activity c;
public Dialog d;
public Button yes, no;
public   TextView rn, ra, rr, rh, rw, rc, re, bn, ba, br, bh, bw, bc, be;


public void setDialog(String redName, String redAge, String redRecord, String redHeight,
                      String redWeight, String redCity, String redExp,String blueName, String blueAge,
                      String blueRecord, String blueHeight,
                      String blueWeight, String blueCity, String blueExp){

    rn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRName);
    ra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRAge);
    rr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRRecord);
    rh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRHeight);
    rw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRWeight);
    rc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRCity);
    re = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRExp);
    bn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBName);
    ba = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBAge);
    br = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBRecord);
    bh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBHeight);
    bw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBWeight);
    bc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBCity);
    be = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBExp);

<----------Where the NullPointer is being thrown----------->
    rn.setText(redName);
    ra.setText(redAge);
    rr.setText(redRecord);
    rh.setText(redHeight);
    rw.setText(redWeight);
    rc.setText(redCity);
    re.setText(redExp);
    bn.setText(blueName);
    ba.setText(blueAge);
    br.setText(blueRecord);
    bh.setText(blueHeight);
    bw.setText(blueWeight);
    bc.setText(blueCity);
    be.setText(blueExp);


}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
    no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDone);
    yes.setOnClickListener(this);
    no.setOnClickListener(this);



}





public DialogClass(Activity a) {
    super(a);
    this.c = a;



}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bPlay:
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.bDone:
            dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    dismiss();
}

}
```

**LogCat**

```
 10-05 18:48:01.843      994-994/com.codealchemist.clashmma E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.codealchemist.clashmma.DialogClass.setDialog(DialogClass.java:43)
        at com.codealchemist.clashmma.databaseFightCard$1.onItemClick(databaseFightCard.java:71)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The LogCat is point to my `DialogClass` on the line

> rn.setText(redName);

I have never set the text to a custom built dialog, so please explain what I am doing wrong.

---

**EDIT DUE TO blackbelt**  This is how I tried to do a `class member`. If it is not obvious by my reputation, I am a beginner so please explain a better way to do this:

**Changed this in my activity that calls for the dialog**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            HomeItem homeItem = (HomeItem) adapter.getItem(position);
            DialogClass dialogClass = new DialogClass(homeItem);


            dialogClass.show();
        }
    });
```

**Changed this in my `DialogClass`**

```
    public DialogClass(HomeItem context) {
    super(context);
    this.hi = context;

}
```

Then in my `onCreate` of my `DialogClass`:

```
    rn.setText(hi.getHomeItemRedName());
    bn.setText(hi.getHomeItemBlueName());
```

Because I had to use Context of `HomeItem`, or whatever I did I have to make my `HomeItem` class extend `Context`. I had to `@Override` about 80 methods:

```
 public class HomeItem extends Context {
private int HomeItemID;


private String HomeItemRedName, HomeItemRedAge, HomeItemRedRecord, HomeItemRedHeight, HomeItemRedWeight,
HomeItemRedCity, HomeItemRedExp;
private String HomeItemBlueName, HomeItemBlueAge, HomeItemBlueRecord, HomeItemBlueHeight, HomeItemBlueWeight,
HomeItemBlueCity, HomeItemBlueExp;

public int getHomeItemID() {
    return HomeItemID;
}
public void setHomeItemID(int ID) {
    this.HomeItemID = ID;
}

public String getHomeItemRedName() {
    return HomeItemRedName;
}
public void setHomeItemRedName(String Name) {
    this.HomeItemRedName = Name;
}

public String getHomeItemRedAge(){

    return HomeItemRedAge;
}
public void setHomeItemRedAge(String Age){
    if (Age == null)
        this.HomeItemRedAge = "Unknown";
    this.HomeItemRedAge = Age;
}

public String getHomeItemRedRecord(){
    return HomeItemRedRecord;
}
public void setHomeItemRedRecord(String Record){
    if (Record == null)
        this.HomeItemRedRecord = "Unknown";
    this.HomeItemRedRecord = Record;
}
public String getHomeItemRedHeight(){
    return HomeItemRedHeight;
}
public void setHomeItemRedHeight(String Height){
    if (Height == null)
        this.HomeItemRedHeight = "Unknown";
    this.HomeItemRedHeight = Height;
}

public String getHomeItemRedWeight(){
    return HomeItemRedWeight;
}
public void setHomeItemRedWeight(String Weight){
    if (Weight == null)
        this.HomeItemRedWeight = "Unknown";
    this.HomeItemRedWeight = Weight;
}

public String getHomeItemRedCity(){
    return HomeItemRedCity;
}
public void setHomeItemRedCity(String City){
    if (City == null)
        this.HomeItemRedCity = "Unknown";
    this.HomeItemRedCity = City;
}

public String getHomeItemRedExp(){
    return HomeItemRedExp;
}
public void setHomeItemRedExp(String Exp){
    if (Exp == null)
        this.HomeItemRedExp = "Unknown";
    this.HomeItemRedExp = Exp;
}
//Blue side
public String getHomeItemBlueName(){

    return HomeItemBlueName;
}
public void setHomeItemBlueName(String Name){
    this.HomeItemBlueName = Name;
}

public String getHomeItemBlueAge(){
    return HomeItemBlueAge;
}
public void setHomeItemBlueAge(String Age){
    if (Age == null)
        this.HomeItemBlueAge = "Unknown";
    this.HomeItemBlueAge = Age;
}
public String getHomeItemBlueRecord(){
    return HomeItemBlueRecord;
}
public void setHomeItemBlueRecord(String Record){
    if (Record == null)
        this.HomeItemBlueRecord = "Unknown";
    this.HomeItemBlueRecord = Record;
}

public String getHomeItemBlueHeight(){
    return HomeItemBlueHeight;
}
public void setHomeItemBlueHeight(String Height){
    if (Height == null)
        this.HomeItemBlueHeight = "Unknown";
    this.HomeItemBlueHeight = Height;
}

public String getHomeItemBlueWeight(){
    return HomeItemBlueWeight;
}
public void setHomeItemBlueWeight(String Weight){
    if (Weight == null)
        this.HomeItemBlueWeight = "Unknown";
    this.HomeItemBlueWeight = Weight;
}

public String getHomeItemBlueCity(){
    return HomeItemBlueCity;
}
public void setHomeItemBlueCity(String City){
    if (City == null)
        this.HomeItemBlueCity = "Unknown";
    this.HomeItemBlueCity= City;
}

public String getHomeItemBlueExp(){
    return HomeItemBlueExp;
}
public void setHomeItemBlueExp(String Exp){
    if (Exp == null)
        this.HomeItemBlueExp = "Unknown";
    this.HomeItemBlueExp = Exp;
}

@Override
public AssetManager getAssets() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Resources getResources() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public PackageManager getPackageManager() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public ContentResolver getContentResolver() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Looper getMainLooper() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setTheme(int i) {

}

@Override
public Resources.Theme getTheme() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getPackageName() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public ApplicationInfo getApplicationInfo() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getPackageResourcePath() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getPackageCodePath() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String s, int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public FileInputStream openFileInput(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public FileOutputStream openFileOutput(String s, int i) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean deleteFile(String s) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public File getFileStreamPath(String s) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public File getFilesDir() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public File getExternalFilesDir(String s) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public File getObbDir() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public File getCacheDir() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public File getExternalCacheDir() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String[] fileList() {
    return new String[0];
}

@Override
public File getDir(String s, int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String s, int i, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory cursorFactory) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String s, int i, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory cursorFactory, DatabaseErrorHandler databaseErrorHandler) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean deleteDatabase(String s) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public File getDatabasePath(String s) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String[] databaseList() {
    return new String[0];
}

@Override
public Drawable getWallpaper() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Drawable peekWallpaper() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getWallpaperDesiredMinimumWidth() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getWallpaperDesiredMinimumHeight() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void setWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {

}

@Override
public void setWallpaper(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

}

@Override
public void clearWallpaper() throws IOException {

}

@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {

}

@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void startActivities(Intent[] intents) {

}

@Override
public void startActivities(Intent[] intents, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void startIntentSender(IntentSender intentSender, Intent intent, int i, int i2, int i3) throws IntentSender.SendIntentException {

}

@Override
public void startIntentSender(IntentSender intentSender, Intent intent, int i, int i2, int i3, Bundle bundle) throws IntentSender.SendIntentException {

}

@Override
public void sendBroadcast(Intent intent) {

}

@Override
public void sendBroadcast(Intent intent, String s) {

}

@Override
public void sendOrderedBroadcast(Intent intent, String s) {

}

@Override
public void sendOrderedBroadcast(Intent intent, String s, BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver, Handler handler, int i, String s2, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void sendBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle userHandle) {

}

@Override
public void sendBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle userHandle, String s) {

}

@Override
public void sendOrderedBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle userHandle, String s, BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver, Handler handler, int i, String s2, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void sendStickyBroadcast(Intent intent) {

}

@Override
public void sendStickyOrderedBroadcast(Intent intent, BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver, Handler handler, int i, String s, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void removeStickyBroadcast(Intent intent) {

}

@Override
public void sendStickyBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle userHandle) {

}

@Override
public void sendStickyOrderedBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle userHandle, BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver, Handler handler, int i, String s, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void removeStickyBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle userHandle) {

}

@Override
public Intent registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter intentFilter) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Intent registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter intentFilter, String s, Handler handler) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver) {

}

@Override
public ComponentName startService(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean stopService(Intent intent) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean bindService(Intent intent, ServiceConnection serviceConnection, int i) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void unbindService(ServiceConnection serviceConnection) {

}

@Override
public boolean startInstrumentation(ComponentName componentName, String s, Bundle bundle) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public Object getSystemService(String s) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int checkPermission(String s, int i, int i2) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int checkCallingPermission(String s) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int checkCallingOrSelfPermission(String s) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void enforcePermission(String s, int i, int i2, String s2) {

}

@Override
public void enforceCallingPermission(String s, String s2) {

}

@Override
public void enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(String s, String s2) {

}

@Override
public void grantUriPermission(String s, Uri uri, int i) {

}

@Override
public void revokeUriPermission(Uri uri, int i) {

}

@Override
public int checkUriPermission(Uri uri, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int checkCallingUriPermission(Uri uri, int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int checkCallingOrSelfUriPermission(Uri uri, int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int checkUriPermission(Uri uri, String s, String s2, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void enforceUriPermission(Uri uri, int i, int i2, int i3, String s) {

}

@Override
public void enforceCallingUriPermission(Uri uri, int i, String s) {

}

@Override
public void enforceCallingOrSelfUriPermission(Uri uri, int i, String s) {

}

@Override
public void enforceUriPermission(Uri uri, String s, String s2, int i, int i2, int i3, String s3) {

}

@Override
public Context createPackageContext(String s, int i) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Context createConfigurationContext(Configuration configuration) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Context createDisplayContext(Display display) {
    return null;
}
```

Compiling this, in my LogCat, I receive this error:

```
  10-06 18:42:59.465      785-785/com.codealchemist.clashmma E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:154)
        at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:131)
        at com.codealchemist.clashmma.DialogClass.<init>(DialogClass.java:83)
        at com.codealchemist.clashmma.databaseFightCard$1.onItemClick(databaseFightCard.java:70)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**I ALSO TRIED THIS**

```
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            HomeItem homeItem = (HomeItem) adapter.getItem(position);
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(databaseFightCard.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = (dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.dimAmount = 0.5f;
            dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);


            Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
            Button done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDone);
            TextView rn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRName);
            TextView ra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRAge);
            TextView rr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRRecord);
            TextView rh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRHeight);
            TextView rw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRWeight);
            TextView rc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRCity);
            TextView re = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRExp);
            TextView bn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBName);
            TextView ba = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBAge);
            TextView br = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBRecord);
            TextView bh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBHeight);
            TextView bw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBWeight);
            TextView bc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBCity);
            TextView be = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBExp);

            rn.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedName()+"");
            ra.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedAge()+"");
            rr.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedRecord()+"");
            rh.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedHeight()+"");
            rw.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedWeight()+"");
            rc.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedCity()+"");
            re.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedExp()+"");
            bn.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueName()+"");
            ba.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueAge()+"");
            br.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueRecord()+"");
            bh.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueHeight()+"");
            bw.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueWeight()+"");
            bc.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueCity()+"");
            be.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueExp()+"");

            play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Still getting `NullPointerException` on

```
 rn.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedName()+"");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually really simple. I just ditched the Dialog class, and did it all here in my onClick.

```
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            HomeItem homeItem = (HomeItem) adapter.getItem(position);
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(databaseFightCard.this);


            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            window.requestFeature(window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);



           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) databaseFightCard.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null, false);
           dialog.setContentView(relative);



            Button play = (Button) relative.findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
            Button done = (Button) relative.findViewById(R.id.bDone);
            TextView rn = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRName);
            TextView ra = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRAge);
            TextView rr = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRRecord);
            TextView rh = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRHeight);
            TextView rw = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRWeight);
            TextView rc = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRCity);
            TextView re = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRExp);
            TextView bn = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBName);
            TextView ba = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBAge);
            TextView br = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBRecord);
            TextView bh = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBHeight);
            TextView bw = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBWeight);
            TextView bc = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBCity);
            TextView be = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBExp);


            rn.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedName()+"");
            ra.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedAge()+"");
            rr.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedRecord()+"");
            rh.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedHeight()+"");
            rw.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedWeight()+"");
            rc.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedCity()+"");
            re.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedExp()+"");
            bn.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueName()+"");
            ba.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueAge()+"");
            br.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueRecord()+"");
            bh.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueHeight()+"");
            bw.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueWeight()+"");
            bc.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueCity()+"");
            be.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueExp()+"");


            play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();




        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`setDialog` is called before the Dialog's `onCreate` . Instead of passing all the Strings to setDialog you can pass a `HomeItem` reference and you can keep it as class member. Inside the onCreate, after `setContentView` you can perform all the `findViewById` and set the text accordingly

Edit

```
public class DialogClass extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

public Activity c;
public Dialog d; 
public Button yes, no;
public   TextView rn, ra, rr, rh, rw, rc, re, bn, ba, br, bh, bw, bc, be;

private HomeItem homeItem;
public void setDialog(HomeItem homeItem){
 this.homeItem = homeItem;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDone);
yes.setOnClickListener(this);
no.setOnClickListener(this);

rn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRName);
ra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRAge);
rr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRRecord);
rh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRHeight);
rw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRWeight);
rc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRCity);
re = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRExp);
bn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBName);
ba = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBAge);
br = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBRecord);
bh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBHeight);
bw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBWeight);
bc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBCity);
be = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBExp);


rn.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedName());
// the rest of your code
```

}
  // other code
}

Comment: I see what your saying, could you show me an example? I am not sure how to do this...

Comment: I don't know what a class member is.

Comment: class member is java basic. For instance, after you declared your class DialogClass, you wrote public Activity c; In this case c is a class member

Comment: OK I see. How would I write a class member to reference one line in my array?

Comment: I did some research and gave it a shot. Please see my addition "EDIT DUE TO blackbelt"

Comment: I meant something really different. You really misunderstood me